# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'astype' npy files

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix, attributeerror

I am trying to read a npz folder. My zipped folder (cora.npz) has npy files in an array format. When I try to load a sparse graph from a numpy binary file, I get this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-e58ac31009ee> in <module>
----> 1 _A_obs, _X_obs, _z_obs = utils.load_npz('data/cora.npz')
     2 _A_obs = _A_obs + _A_obs.T
     3 _A_obs[_A_obs > 1] = 1
     4 lcc = utils.largest_connected_components(_A_obs)
     5 

~/Jupyter_Projects/NETTACK ALGORITHM/nettack/utils.py in load_npz(file_name)
    28 
    29         if 'attr_data' in loader:
---> 30             attr_matrix = sp.csr_matrix((loader['attr_data'], loader['attr_indices'],
    31                                                    loader['attr_indptr']), shape=loader['attr_shape'])
    32         else:
```

My code looks like this:

```
if not file_name.endswith('.npz'):
        file_name += '.npz'
    with np.load(file_name) as loader:
        loader = dict(loader)
        adj_matrix = sp.csr_matrix((loader['adj_data'], loader['adj_indices'],
                                              loader['adj_indptr']), shape=loader['adj_shape'])

        if 'attr_data' in loader:
            attr_matrix = sp.csr_matrix((loader['attr_data'], loader['attr_indices'],
                                                   loader['attr_indptr']), shape=loader['attr_shape'])
        else:
            attr_matrix = None

        labels = loader.get('labels')
        #print(labels)

    return adj_matrix, attr_matrix, labels
```

When I try to read my files with np.load('adj_indptr.npy',allow_pickle = True) the reading part finishes successfully and prints the numbers inside it in an array format.

Comment: That's not the full traceback, is it?  The `npz` layout looks a bit like the one used by `scipy.sparse.load_npz`, but apparently is `NETTACK` specific.  Without that package or a sample `npz` we can't help.

Comment: NETTACK algorithm is already given and they have a dataset which they train the model on it. I have my own dataset with the same format and in same logic like they do but it keeps giving me this error. Thanks for the answer.